# Is it possible to recover browser data lost due to formatting?

Tags: data-recovery, formatting

I accidentally formatted my computer, and therefore lost my web browsers. I used to work with multiple browsers (Google Chrome, IE, Firefox, etc.), and some of my vital web searches were stored in their history. Is it possible to recover the browsers’ history in their original form as they were on the day my computer was formatted?

Comment: Use file recover of your choice to recover the files.  If you have written data since you performed the format, your chances of recovering the files, are very low but still worth a try.

Answer (score -1):

If you had previously signed in with an account and turned on the sync, then yes it is possible to recover the synced data like history, bookmarks etc. You need to install the browser(Chrome/Firefox) sign up with the account that you previously signed in with and it will start synchronizing the data which will include the one that you previously synced with your account. But I'm not sure if IE has synchronization options. It should work fine in FF/Chrome.